# Why is -ln x is not equal to 1/ln x?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

I am doing differential equation now and I need to convert them into the proper form in order to do my homogeneous differential equation. So now I just found out that -ln x is not equal to 1 / ln x. I thought it should be able to convert to ln x to the negative 1 then I can put it into the form 1/ ln x. Can anyone explain about it?

Comment: Why should it be equal? – But you have $-\ln x = \ln (1/x)$, perhaps that is what you are looking for

Comment: There aren't many values of $u$ for which $-u$ equals $1/u$...

Comment: Ok so what is equal is -lnx and ln (1/x) right?

Comment: Right. If you had $\ln x = 2$, what would $- \ln x$ be? And $1/(\ln x)$?

Comment: Well i think i forgot the fundamental of logarithms that when you want to convert 2lnx into another form which is ln x to 2, it is not the whole thing to 2 it is just x to the 2. Thanks for solving my doubt.

Comment: Did you mean $(\ln{x})^{-1}=\frac{1}{\ln{x}}$? Or perhaps, $-\ln{x}=\frac{1}{\ln(-x)}$?

Comment: I am sorry i can't read your equation from the app.

Comment: You're doing math.stackexchange from mobile??? Wow, good luck with that.

Comment: Ok i can read that from chrome, i was talking about −lnx=1/ln(x) but i found out that it was wrong and now i know why it is wrong too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is $-\ln(x)$ is not equal to $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$ ?

Because  $\space -\ln(x)=\ln(\frac{1}{x})\space $
and $\space \ln(\frac{1}{x})\space $ is not equal to $\space \frac{1}{\ln(x)}$

In general, for most of the functions $f(x)$ we don't have $f(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{f(x)}$